# Returning JSON response and reconstructing HTML table through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET controller action which basically returns a JSON response after a POST call to server like this:

```
 responseDetails.Add(new ActiveSubsPayPal
                        {
                            ProfileID = item.ProfileId,
                            Status = profileType,
                            LastTimePaid = DateTime.Now,
                            NextTimePayment = DateTime.Now,
                            BillingCycle = subType,
                            TotalCyclesCompleted = 2,
                            TotalAmountPaid = 40.0d
                        });
```

So as you can see the response details is a list which contains those properties. List can have 0, 1 or 50 records in it... Now what I do after this is I convert it to JSON like this:

```
return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(responseDetails);


[{"ProfileID":"123","Status":"Not active profile","LastTimePaid":"2016-12-18T21:46:27Z","NextTimePayment":null,"BillingCycle":"Each year","TotalCyclesCompleted":"1","TotalAmountPaid":"180.00"}]
```

Now here is the HTML/jQuery part:

```
 $(".scanSubs").click(function () {
        $.post("/Administrator/GetUserSubs", { uid: $(this).closest('tr').find('.idrowSubs').attr("value") })
        .done(function (response) {

           // reconstruct the HTML table here and inject recontructed HTML => JSON into the DOM

        });
    });

 <table class="table table-striped" id="tableSubs">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>PROFILE ID</th>

                   <th>Status</th>
                   <th>Last Time Paid</th>
                   <th>Next Payment</th>
                   <th>Billing Cycles</th>
                    <th>Total Billing Cycles</th>
                       <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                   </tr>

               </thead>
                <tbody>

                   <tr>
                       <td><b>123</b></td>


                       <td>Active</td>


                       <td>12.12.2012</td>


                       <td>12.12.2012</td>


                       <td>4 Weeks</td>


                       <td>12</td>


                       <td>$122.23</td>
                   </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

How can I now actually reconstruct the JSON into HTML and perform injection into the browser so that I can see the results ? Can someone help me out ?

Comment: P.S. Guys , each record in JSON array should match 1 table row in the table itself, which is what's confusing me mostly...

Comment: It would be easier to return a partial view of the table body, but if you want to return json, the `response` is an array, so you just need to loop though each item in the array and access its properties to generate your html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you show me how to do this? Btw. if I returned a partial view, how would I actually fill the data source for the table if It's not set initially upon the page load ? =D

Comment: You now have a couple of answers (albeit not great ones). Create a template in the view (hidden) and clone it and set the value/text or the elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay I think I understand u. Btw. Can I do it like this... I  set the table's data source for a viewbag.results which is initially empty, and then when the action is triggered, I Simply set the data source of this viewbag to new list  and return the partial view? Then simply update the view?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. When you say _datasource_, are you using a jquery plugin?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no, just plain jquery and .NET :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139835/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please iterate through each record in the JSON using  **$.each(response, function (idx, obj) {}** and create html like below

```
 var tableHtml = "<table class="table table-striped" id="tableSubs"><thead><tr><th>PROFILE ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Last Time Paid</th><th>Next Payment</th><th>Billing Cycles</th><th>Total Billing Cycles</th><th>Total Amount Paid</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                        $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                            tableHtml += "<tr>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.ProfileID + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.Status + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.LastTimePaid + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.NextTimePayment + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.BillingCycle + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.TotalCyclesCompleted + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.TotalAmountPaid + "</td>";
                            tableHtml += "</tr>";
                        });
                        tableHtml += "</tbody></table>";
                        $("#TABLEID").html(tableHtml);
```

see with sample data

```
 var tableHtml = "<table class='table table-striped' ><thead><tr><th>PROFILE ID</th><th>Status</th><th>Last Time Paid</th><th>Next Payment</th><th>Billing Cycles</th><th>Total Billing Cycles</th><th>Total Amount Paid</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            $.each([{"ProfileID":"123","Status":"Not active profile","LastTimePaid":"2016-12-18T21:46:27Z","NextTimePayment":null,"BillingCycle":"Each year","TotalCyclesCompleted":"1","TotalAmountPaid":"180.00"}], function (idx, obj) {
                tableHtml += "<tr>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.ProfileID + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.Status + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.LastTimePaid + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.NextTimePayment + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.BillingCycle + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.TotalCyclesCompleted + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "<td>" + obj.TotalAmountPaid + "</td>";
                tableHtml += "</tr>";
            });
            tableHtml += "</tbody></table>";
            $("#TABLEID").html(tableHtml);
```

Comment: Ratsheesh it says here: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"ProfileID":"12345678","Status":"Not active profile","LastTimePaid":"2017-03-30T21:34:21Z","NextTimePayment":null,"BillingCycle":"Each month","TotalCyclesCompleted":"4","TotalAmountPaid":"119.96"}]  at isArrayLike  :(

Comment: make sure that your response has data and it is a valid JSON
use .JSON.parse(data)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the placeholder to replace the html, looking at your html only row need the multiple so make a template of row.

```
var template = "
    <tr>
       <td><b>{{ProfileID}}</b></td>
       <td>{{Status}}</td>
       <td>{{NextTimePayment}}</td>
       <td>{{LastTimePaid}}</td>
       <td>{{BillingCycle}}</td>
       <td>{{TotalCyclesCompleted}}</td>
       <td>{{TotalAmountPaid}}</td>
    </tr>"
```

Put the Remaining HTML in the html file

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableSubs">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                   <th>PROFILE ID</th>

                   <th>Status</th>
                   <th>Last Time Paid</th>
                   <th>Next Payment</th>
                   <th>Billing Cycles</th>
                    <th>Total Billing Cycles</th>
                       <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
                   </tr>

               </thead>
                <tbody id="DynamicResponse">
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

jQUery Code to use this

```
    $.each({"ProfileID":"123","Status":"Not active profile","LastTimePaid":"2016-12-18T21:46:27Z","NextTimePayment":null,"BillingCycle":"Each year","TotalCyclesCompleted":"1","TotalAmountPaid":"180.00"}, function( k, v ) {
     template = template.replace("{{"+k+"}}",v);

    });
 $("#DynamicResponse").append(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you simply need to loop through the `response` array that's returned from the AJAX request, along with some simple date formatting. Try this:

```js
var response = [{
  "ProfileID": "123",
  "Status": "Not active profile",
  "LastTimePaid": "2016-12-18T21:46:27Z",
  "NextTimePayment": null,
  "BillingCycle": "Each year",
  "TotalCyclesCompleted": "1",
  "TotalAmountPaid": "180.00"
},{
  "ProfileID": "456",
  "Status": "Not active profile",
  "LastTimePaid": "2017-12-18T21:46:27Z",
  "NextTimePayment": null,
  "BillingCycle": "Each year",
  "TotalCyclesCompleted": "2",
  "TotalAmountPaid": "290.00"
}]

function formatDate(dateString) {
  if (!dateString)
    return '';
    
  var d = new Date(dateString);
  return ('00' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + d.getFullYear()
}

// in the done() handler...
var html = '';
response.forEach(function(obj) { 
   html += '<tr>';
   html += '<td>' + obj.ProfileID + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + obj.Status + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + formatDate(obj.LastTimePaid) + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + formatDate(obj.NextTimePayment) + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + obj.BillingCycle + '</td>';
   html += '<td>' + obj.TotalCyclesCompleted + '</td>';
   html += '<td>$' + obj.TotalAmountPaid + '</td>';
   html += '</tr>';   
});

$('#tableSubs').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped" id="tableSubs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>PROFILE ID</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Last Time Paid</th>
      <th>Next Payment</th>
      <th>Billing Cycles</th>
      <th>Total Billing Cycles</th>
      <th>Total Amount Paid</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>123</b></td>
      <td>Active</td>
      <td>12.12.2012</td>
      <td>12.12.2012</td>
      <td>4 Weeks</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>$122.23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```